# Fastlane Screengrab - don't include timestamp in screenshot file names

Tags: java, android, fastlane

### Background

I am automating taking screenshots of my Android app using [Fastlane's screengrab](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/screengrab/). However, the default behavior of `Screengrab.screenshot()` adds a timestamp to the file name. This is undesirable and even unexpected.

[This issue on Github](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5988) suggests extending `ScreenshotCallback` to remove the timestamp from the file name. I found the default behavior is implemented in `FileWritingScreenshotCallback`, so decided to extend it and override `getScreenshotFile()`:

```
class ScreenshotCallback extends FileWritingScreenshotCallback {
    public ScreenshotCallback(Context appContext) {
        super(appContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected File getScreenshotFile(File screenshotDirectory, String screenshotName) {
        return new File(screenshotDirectory, screenshotName);
    }
}
```

Then my JUnit test to take screenshots looks like this:

### Code

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    />

    <!-- Other stuff -->
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Screenshots.java

```
public class Screenshots {
    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<LiteActivity> activityRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(
        MainActivity.class
    );

    private ScreenshotCallback screenshotCallback;
    private UiAutomatorScreenshotStrategy screenshotStrategy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        Instrumentation inst = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        Context context = inst.getTargetContext();
        screenshotCallback = new ScreenshotCallback(context);
        screenshotStrategy = new UiAutomatorScreenshotStrategy();

        ActivityScenario<LiteActivity> scenario = activityRule.getScenario();
        Screengrab.setDefaultScreenshotStrategy(new UiAutomatorScreenshotStrategy());
    }

    @Test
    public void takeScreenshot() {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        Screengrab.screenshot("MainScreen", screenshotStrategy, screenshotCallback);
    }
}
```

When I run this with `bundle exec fastlane screengrab`, I get the following output:

```
[22:31:52]: $ adb.exe -s emulator-5554 pull /sdcard/com.example/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots C:/Users/user-name/AppData/Local/Temp/d20210808-12584-jlogjl
ls: /sdcard/Android/data/com.example/files/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[22:31:53]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/user/0/com.example/files/com.example/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[22:31:53]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/com.example/files/com.example/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[22:31:53]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/com.example/app_screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[22:31:53]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/com.example/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[22:31:53]: Exit status: 1
[22:31:53]: Screenshots copied to fastlane/metadata/android/en-US/images/phoneScreenshots
[22:31:53]: Make sure you've used Screengrab.screenshot() in your tests and that your expected tests are being run.
```

Why are none of my screenshots on the device? I don't see any obvious errors in the logcat. If I do `Screengrab.screenshot("MainScreen");` instead of `Screengrab.screenshot("MainScreen", screenshotStrategy, screenshotCallback);`, the screenshot file is copied to my development file system just fine. What can I do to debug this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screengrab supports it.

You must find Screengrabfile with configuration and set field

```
use_timestamp_suffix: false
```

[Documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/screengrab/)

[Merged pull request with this changes](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/14781/files)

Comment: That's an even better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the correct syntax in `Screengrabfile` is `use_timestamp_suffix(false)`.

Comment: And also, it doesn't appear to work. I'm still getting files with timestamp suffixes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Attach Screengrabfile in question, please

Comment: I'm looking into this further. I think I need to update the gradle dependency.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Which version of library are you using?

Comment: I had `androidTestImplementation 'tools.fastlane:screengrab:1.0.0'`. Looks like `2.0.0` is the current version.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The latest version is 2.1.0